# get search result output from mysql in hidden side bar on click button without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is a piece of code i tried but it is not working for me i am trying to get the ouput in side bar without refreshing the page.Actually i want when i click on search button the result should display in side nav bar

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s-results').load('search.php').show();


  $('#search-btn').click(function() {
    showValues();
  });

  $(function() {
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
      showValues();
      return false;
    });
  });

  function showValues() {
    $('#s-results').html('<img src="images/loader.gif" />');

    $.post('search.php', {
        name: form.name.value
      },

      function(result) {
        $('#s-results').html(result).show();
      });
  }

});
```

```css
{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-button {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: fff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hide-menu {
  background-color: #336ca6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.show-menu {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<center>
  <br>

  <div style='display:none;'>
    <img src="images/loader.gif" />
  </div>

  <form action="" name="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="fn" Placeholder="Search Something..." style="width:300px; padding:8px;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="menu-button" style="padding:8px;" />
  </form>
  <br>

  <div id="s-results">
    the Search results is showing here when i tried with hidden side bar it is not showing
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: have a look and help me out

Comment: what do you have in the results variable?

Comment: in result variable i have the data from sql server